# react native suggest a new strong password

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to implement suggest a new password feature into my app, But instead of a password it shows a yellow background when we press return from the password field how to solve this

```
  <TextInput
    placeholder={placeHolderText}
    contentType={contentType}
    value={value}
    autoCorrect={false}
    passwordRules={passwordRules}  //  'required: lower; required: upper; required: digit; required: [@]; minlength: 8;'
    textContentType={textContentType}  //   textContentType="newPassword"
    keyboardType={keyboardType === 'number' ? 'number-pad' : 'default'}
    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
    returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
    onPress={onPress}
   
  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Combining @iamgerardm solution with a Keyboard dismiss on submit seems to get the desired behavior back.
`import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

```
blurOnSubmit={false}
onSubmitEditing={()=> Keyboard.dismiss()}`
```