# How to make iOS suggest a strong password on react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am looking to implement the "Suggest strong password" feature from iOS on my app. My text input looks like this:

```
<TextInput
  textContentType="newPassword"
  passwordRules="minlength: 8;"
  value={password}
  onChangeText={setPassword}
  secureTextEntry
  autoCapitalize="none"
/>
```

This should work with the `textContentType="newPassword"` but the yellow bar with suggestion just doesn't show. I only get `Passwords` option on the prediction bar that opens my password storage.

I have keychain turned on and I've confirmed that the feature works for other apps like Reddit so the problem is not in the system settings. How do I make this work?

*P.S. I am aware of [react native suggest a new strong password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673516/react-native-suggest-a-new-strong-password) and [React Native Expo iOS Use Strong Password feature not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526214/react-native-expo-ios-use-strong-password-feature-not-working), the first is not the same as my issue and second uses expo which I'm not.*

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with `secureTextEntry` - I haven't done enough research to know why but the below may work for you.

Not a optimal solution, but adding blurOnSubmit, and a keyboard Dismiss on submit seems to get the desired behavior back:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

<TextInput
   ...
   blurOnSubmit={false}
   onSubmitEditing={()=> Keyboard.dismiss()}
/>
```

Or if you prefer, this may work for you also.

```
textContentType={'oneTimeCode'}
```

Ref: [React Native - secureTextEntry Disable IOS 13+ Strong Password behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038086/react-native-securetextentry-disable-ios-13-strong-password-behavior)

Comment: Doesn't work on IOS16